# Does the centralizer dimension of a matrix depend only on the partition appearing in the Frobenius normal form (sublocks sizes)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider an $n \times n$ matrix $M$ over field $F$.
Over any field (not necessarily algebraically closed) any matrix can be conjugated to the Frobenius normal form ([e.g. Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_normal_form)). It becomes block-diagonal and so sizes of blocks define some partition of $n = \sum_i b_i $.

Consider centralizer of $M$, i.e. set: $C(M) = \{ B \in Mat(n,F) : BM=MB \} $  of all matrices which commute with $M$.
It is clearly a linear subspace of $Mat(n,F)$ and so it has some dimension $d$.

**Question 1:** Is it true that dimension of the centralizer of a matrix depends only on the partition $n = \sum_i b_i $ (i.e. on integers $b_i$) appearing in the Frobenius normal form ?

If true:

**Question 2:** How to express the dimension of centralizer in terms of the partition $b_i$ ?

**Question 2b:** Is it true that the dimension of centralizer given by the formula $\sum t_i^2$, where $t_i$ comes from the transpose Young diagram to $b_i$ ?

If 1 is true:

**Question 3:** If $M$ is in Frobenius normal form, what can be the said about the form of matrices commuting with it ? For example if there are two blocks of unequal sizes, then seems commuting matrix will also have same block-diagonal form ?

**Examples:** if $M$ is a matrix at general position i.e. all eigenvalues are different (may be in some algebraic extension of $F$), then all above is true and simple: Frobenius normal form consists of just one block of maximal size $n\times n$, the space of commuting matrices has dimension $n$, which is $\sum 1^2$ (since $1+1+...+1$ is transpose Young diagram $n$), question 3 is tautologically true, since any matrix is block diagonal for block size is $n\times n$.

Other extreme is $M$ - scalar matrix (i.e. diagonal with all values on the diagonal are equal), its Frobenius normal form is $M$ itself, and  we have $n$ blocks of sizes $1\times 1$ , everything commute with it - so $n^2$ is commutant dimension, which is $n^2$ since transpose to $n=1+1+...+1$ is partition of one term $n$.

In case matrix is diagonalizable and has eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ with multiplicities $c_i$, then dimension of the centralizer is clearly $\sum c_i^2$, so probably these $c_i$ corresponds to $t_i$ in the question ?
(See also [For non-diagonalizable matrices, the dimension of centralizer can be different from $\sum\limits_{j=1}^k d_j^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3270502/21498) )

**Example - more complicated:**
The sizes of blocks in FNF are exactly the degrees of polynomials $f_i$ entering the FNF theorem.  They satisfy : $f_i|f_{i+1}$. That means:

**if there are two blocks of the same size in FNF, then they are identically the same  !**

So consider example of matrix with FNF when all blocks of the same size, say $k$, so $k|n$, say $n=k*l$. Now it is

**easy to describe what is commuting with a matrix which consists of several identical blocks: because it can be represented as tensor product $Block \otimes Id_{l} $, and hence $Com(Block) \otimes Mat(l) $ is commuting with such matrix.**

$Com(Frobenius~ block)$ are just polynoms from block itself, so it has dimension as vector space equal to the size of the block i.e. to $k$.
And hence dimension of the vector space $Com(Block) \otimes Mat(l) $ is equal to $k*l^2$.
That is exactly was in required in questions 1,2,2b.
Indeed Young diagram for our matrix is just rectangular $k \times l$ ,
so its transpose is $l\times k$, so summing up heights of columns we get $\sum_i l^2 = k*l^2$.

**Remark:** The top degree polynomial of $f_i$ coincides with the minimal polynomial. The product of all $f_i$ is equal to the characteristic polynomial.

PS

Nice discussion of centralizers is here: [The dimension of centralizer of a Matrix.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1292158/the-dimension-of-centralizer-of-a-matrix)
And also see answers here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1950688/21498

and here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/105076/10446

PSPS

All that should be standard and simple for experts, but I think worth to be discussed here.